# Extract Response Data from Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, servicenow-rest-api

I have this piece of code which creates a new ticket in ServiceNow

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI  -Credential $SNowCreds -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/xml' 
Write-IntoLog $Response.result
```

The output is stored in **$Response** and is as below

```
@{parent=; made_sla=true; caused_by=; watch_list=; upon_reject=Cancel all future Tasks; sys_updated_on=2018-01-11 08:49:50; child_incidents=0; hold_reason=; approval_history=; number=INC0010079; resolved_by=; sys_updated_by=Admin; opened_by=; user_input=; sys_created_on=2018-01-11 08:49:50; sys_domain=; state=In Progress; sys_created_by=Admin; knowledge=false; order=; calendar_stc=; closed_at=; cmdb_ci=; delivery_plan=; impact=2 - Medium; active=true; work_notes_list=; business_service=; priority=2 - High; sys_domain_path=/; rfc=; time_worked=; expected_start=; opened_at=2018-01-11 08:49:50; business_duration=; group_list=; work_end=; caller_id=; reopened_time=; resolved_at=; approval_set=; subcategory=Internal Application; work_notes=; short_description=Issues with Accessing Web URL; close_code=; correlation_display=; delivery_task=; work_start=; assignment_group=; additional_assignee_list=; business_stc=; description=We are facing issues with accessing the portal https://www.inmotion.com. The error Received is a 403 Error and Access to the same; calendar_duration=; close_notes=; notify=Do Not Notify; sys_class_name=Incident; closed_by=; follow_up=; parent_incident=; sys_id=2c40df9edb234300479a7e7dbf96198f; contact_type=; reopened_by=; incident_state=In Progress; urgency=1 - High; problem_id=; company=; reassignment_count=0; activity_due=UNKNOWN; assigned_to=; severity=3 - Low; comments=; approval=Not Yet Requested; sla_due=UNKNOWN; comments_and_work_notes=; due_date=; sys_mod_count=0; reopen_count=0; sys_tags=; escalation=Normal; upon_approval=Proceed to Next Task; correlation_id=; location=; category=Network}
```

From the output I want to extract the number(Incident ID) and also generate a link to the ServiceNow Incident.

However I am unable to extract the **number(Incident ID)**. I tried converting the piece of output to JSON

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI  -Credential $SNowCreds -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/xml' | ConvertTo-Json
```

I tried to navigate it through the nodes. I am still not able to retrieve the **IncidentID**
Request your assistance in the above issue.

Comment: thats not a valid json

Comment: i guess what i meant by my comment is that you cant do `convertfrom-json` if its not a valid json. also `Invoke-WebRequest` does that for you (`ConvertFrom-Json`). But your API returns mangled json and nested...

Answer (score 0):

Without using the 'ConvertTo-Json'

```
 Write-host "The number is  $($response.result.number)"
```

This works.

Other useful reference:
     Powershell ServiceNow API